# How do I iterate through a set of of links and extract the href and store them in a new set?

Tags: java, jsoup

This is what I have so far. I am attempting to loop through my first set of links and extract the HTML tags from each element. Then add the link to a temp set. Finally afterwards it will clear the first set and put all the links back into it. Hopefully this makes sense.

So far my current code is giving me a compile time error for

```
    temp.add(x.attr("href"));
```

Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)").get();

    Elements links = doc.select("body a");

    Set<Element> linkSet = new HashSet<Element>(links);

    Set<Element> temp = new HashSet<Element>();

    for(Element x : linkSet)
        temp.add(x.attr("href"));

    linkSet.clear();

    linkSet.addAll(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html), `attr` is returning a `String`, not an `Element`:

```
Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();
for (Element link: doc.select("body a"))
   links.add(link.attr("href"));
```

Comment: Just to make sure that I have an understanding of what exactly is going on in the code you wrote.. the loop iterates through each Element in doc and adds each href from the doc as a String into links. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Element class you're using but Element.attr(.) probably returns a String and not another Element.